# Can't make arraylist make a list using a index and while loop

Tags: arraylist

I'm trying to make a program in java that you can add people's birthdays, names, birthmonths, and birthyears. I want to be able to print out a list with month and number of people born in each month. I have the following code with 2 classes one as a "person" class and "analyzer" class. Here is the following code,

```
import java.util.*;
/*
 * This project will keep track of which day
 * (1 to 31) and which month (1 to 12)in which
 * people are born.
 * Look to LogAnalyzer for clue.
 */

public class Person
{
private int birthDay;
private int birthMonth;
private int birthYear;
private String name;

 public Person(String name, int birthDay, int birthMonth, int birthYear)
{ 
    this.name = name;
    if(birthDay >= 1 && birthDay <= 31){
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }
    else {
        this.birthDay = -1;
    }

    if(birthMonth >= 1 && birthMonth <= 12 ){
        this.birthMonth = birthMonth;
    }
    else {
        this.birthMonth = -1;
    }

    this.birthYear = birthYear;

}

 public String getName()
{ 
    return name;
}

public int getBirthDay()
{
    return birthDay;
}

  public int getBirthMonth()
{
    return birthMonth;
}

public int getBirthYear()
{
    return birthYear;
}

 public String toString()
{
    return "Name: " + getName() + "    BirthDay: " + getBirthDay() + 
    "    BirthMonth: " + getBirthMonth() + "    BirthYear: " + 
getBirthYear();
}


}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Analyzer
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int []birthDayStats;
private int []birthMonthStats;
private ArrayList people;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Analyzer
 */
public Analyzer()
{
   people = new ArrayList();
}

public void addPerson(String name, int birthDay, int birthMonth, int 
birthYear)
{
    Person person = new Person(name, birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear);
    if(person.getBirthDay()!=-1|| person.getBirthMonth() != -1) {
        people.add(person);
        birthMonthStats [birthMonth]++;
        birthDayStats[birthDay]++;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println ("Your current Birthday is " + birthDay + " or "  
 + birthMonth + " which is not a correct number 1-31 or 1-12 please put in a 
 correct number " );

    }


}

public void printPeople() //prints all people in form:   “  Name: Tom   
Month: 5   Day: 2  Year: 1965”
{
    int index = 0;
    while(index < people.size()){    
        Person person = (Person) people.get(index);    
        System.out.println(person); 
        index++;
    }        
}

public void printMonthList()//prints the number of people born in each month 
Sample output to the right with days being similar
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index < birthMonthStats.length){
        System.out.println (birthMonthStats[index]);
        index++;
    }
}
```

}

the code i'm having trouble is the "printmonthlist" method i'm trying to print it but it doesn't print. I want it to print out the month list of 12 months and the number of people born in each month. If any of you could help me figure it out thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for dates rather than mere integers.  `LocalDate.of( y , m , d )` And [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) & [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) classes may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your arrays. As you can see in my code down here I initialized the arrays with two constants in the `Analyzer` creation.
NB: for readability I just changed a little bit your log in the `printMonthList()` method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Analyzer
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private final static int DAYS_PER_MONTH = 31;
    private final static int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
    private int []birthDayStats;
    private int []birthMonthStats;
    private ArrayList<Person> people;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Analyzer
     */
    public Analyzer()
    {
       this.people = new ArrayList<Person>();
       // A default value of 0 for arrays of integral types is guaranteed by the language spec
       this.birthDayStats = new int[Analyzer.DAYS_PER_MONTH];
       // A default value of 0 for arrays of integral types is guaranteed by the language spec
       this.birthMonthStats = new int[Analyzer.MONTHS_PER_YEAR];
    }

    public void addPerson(String name, int birthDay, int birthMonth, int 
    birthYear)
    {
        Person person = new Person(name, birthDay, birthMonth, birthYear);
        if(person.getBirthDay()!=-1|| person.getBirthMonth() != -1) {
            people.add(person);
            birthMonthStats [birthMonth-1]++;
            birthDayStats[birthDay-1]++;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ("Your current Birthday is " + birthDay + " or "  
     + birthMonth + " which is not a correct number 1-31 or 1-12 please put in a correct number " );

        }


    }

    public void printPeople() //prints all people in form:   “  Name: Tom   Month: 5   Day: 2  Year: 1965”
    {
        int index = 0;
        while(index < people.size()){    
            Person person = (Person) people.get(index);    
            System.out.println(person); 
            index++;
        }        
    }

    public void printMonthList()//prints the number of people born in each month Sample output to the right with days being similar
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < birthMonthStats.length){
            System.out.println ("Month number " + (index+1) + " has " + birthMonthStats[index] + " people");
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now if i wanted to see which month was the most popular how would i do that? ive used public void mostPopularMonth() but i dont know where to start next

Comment: You should loop through `birthMonthStats` looking for the maximum value and saving the index at which you found it. That's your month